# Jquery count each() first item coming back as undefined

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm trying to hide a "Show All" button if there are less than 5 li in a ul but the first ul is coming back as undefined so it is only working for the rest of them. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance...

```
    var count = 0;
    $('article ul').each(function () {
        if (count != 0) {
            var len = $(this).find('li').length;

            if (len < 5) {
                $(this).parent().find('.viewAll').hide();
            }
        }
        count++;
        console.log(len)
    });
```

Comment: When your function runs on the first `ul`, the `count` variable is still `0` and it never enters your `if`. Only after `count` increments for the first time, it does do something, but it's already the second `ul` in the list.

Comment: You can get rid of the `count` variable and incrementor if you use the `index` parameter in the inner function. ex: `.each(function(index, value) {})`. [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, your `len` never gets defined in the first iteration of `each`

There are several ways you can get rid of the `count` variable.

First, `$(selector).each(function(index, element){/* code */})`

`$.each` already tracks the index for you. This index would be identical to your `count`

Another way, since your code wants to skip over the first matching element is to start the `each` after the first one using `'gt()'` selector

```
// gt(0) will start after first element of matching selector
$('article ul:gt(0)').each(function () {    
    var len = $(this).find('li').length;    
    if (len < 5) {
        $(this).parent().find('.viewAll').hide();        
    }    
    console.log(len)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using index instead.